# Admob banner for app with iPad Multitasking / Split View enabled (Swift)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, admob

I am making an app for iPad with multitasking enabled and right now I am trying to implement an Admob banner.

There is an article about doing that in case of multitasking enabled (https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/multiscene?hl=ru) but all code there is written in Objective-C when I'm using Swift.

I tried to translate it but I have no idea how to do that for the piece of code below. What is "requestInitialized"? What it should do and how to write it in Swift?

If anyone has a full code for successful implementing an Admob banner in multitasking app, please help me with it

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  if (!_requestInitialized) {
    [self loadInterstitial];
    _requestInitialized = YES;
  }
}
```

Comment: Instance variables are, by convention, named with an underscore. This is directly accessing the storage for a boolean variable. Identical to `self.requestInitialized` or just `initialized`, depending on scope.

Comment: bshirley, thank you! That's a pity Admob guide doesn't provide info about when and where to implement this variable...

Comment: By default a property will have an ivar synthesized for it automatically using these conventions. You shouldn't be able to access it except inside the class. One thing that commonly suppress this synthesis is provided accessors. When you do that, you're taking responsibility for how it is stored. If you want it synthesized anyway, you can use the `@synthesize` compiler directive. _(I've been using Objective-C for close to 30 years, but I would suggest you go with Swift as in @DrewG's response, if that's an option.)_

Answer (score 4):

For SwiftUI you can add this :

```
request.scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene
```

Answer (score 0):

GoogleAdmob does offer a quick-start [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start) that does show you Swift.. I will also provide some instructions.

Make sure you have the `GoogleMobileAds` pod added to your project and have the correct plist setup.

In your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in your `AppDelegate.swift` add the following:

`GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)`

Drag and drop a normal UIView into your storyboard, give it a width of 320 and a height of 50. Then you can change the class of the view to a `GADBannerView`. Then use the code below and make sure your IBOutlet is connected.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var bannerView: GADBannerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" // Test Banner ID, replace with your ID here.
        bannerView.rootViewController = self
        bannerView.load(GADRequest())

        bannerView.delegate = self
    }


    // MARK: - GADBannerViewDelegate

    func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("Received Ad")
    }

    func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
        print(error)
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you! I already added this code but the problem is that I get this error "<Google> Invalid Request. The GADRequest scene property should be set for
applications that support multi-scene. Treating the unset property as an error
while in test mode." when the multitasking is enabled